# How to enter a record into datagrid first row every time

Tags: c#

I would like my datagridview to focus on first row. Let's say I insert data, it goes in the first row ok. But the second data must be shown in the first row - not the second. How do I do this?

Here is my code:

```
btnEnterAT.Enabled = false;
        if (isFormValid())
        {
            DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("Are You Sure You Want To Assign This Driver?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            if (dialog == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                try
                {


                    {
                        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
                        con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-DEDSEC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CAB;Integrated Security=True";
                        con.Open();
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("BEGIN TRAN; insert into cabphase2(driver_name,LPNO,CODENO,date) values (@driver_name,@lpno,@codeno,@date); DELETE FROM cabphase3 WHERE codeno = @codeno; COMMIT TRAN;", con);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@driver_name", txtDNAMEAT.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lpno", txtLNOAT.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codeno", txtCODENOAT.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", dateTimePicker1.Value);
                        cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        DataGridView1.Rows.Insert(0) //here
                        con.Close();
                        LoadData();
                        ClearData();
                        int temp = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        if (temp > 0) 
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Driver Assigned Successfuly!", "Dispatch Form", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                       }
                        else
                          {
                            MessageBox.Show("TAXI ASSIGNED!", "Dispatch Form", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                          } 

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Taxi Assigned", "Dispatch");
                }
```

Comment: You don’t seem to have added the code where you’re trying to add the row?

Comment: Updated code...

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: In `LoadData` change your code and load the data and sort it by a field that will make the last row appear in the first grid row. Maybe order it by date. Hard to say without seeing the `LoadData` code.

Comment: It is unknown “how” the grid is initially filled with data. If the grid has a `DataSource`, then the code…`DataGridView1.Rows.Insert(0)` … will fail and throw an exception since the code needs to add the rows to the `DataSource` and not directly into the grid. If you are not using a data source… then you should. As commented, sorting would appear the best approach, possibly by “date.”